# iOS UIImagePicker for Videos Crashing Simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using the following code to choose a video on the simulator:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)  // for ipad only
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    imagePicker.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];;
    popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
    [popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems objectAtIndex:0] permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

All is well until the video is chosen and you click the "Use" button.  At this point, I get the "compressing video" indicator and the simulator will lock up and will have to be restarted.  The delegate is never called, and the debugger just shows "running", never to return.

My question is whether:
(a) there is anything obviously wrong with code and
(b) having noticed several posts regarding UIImagePickerController and the simulator (but none just like mine) whether anyone knows if perhaps there is a bug in the simulator that could be causing this.  This is the 6.1 simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine (I suppose that ARC is enabled).
I have the same issue in my project. Running on Simulator causes hangs. Although it works fine on a real device. Probably you should test your code on a real device.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it:

### go to the simulator hardware menu and select TV out: 640x480

### after that try to run your app from xcode

### and then again go to the simulator hardware menu and select TV out: Disabled.